# Batch script printing set command, not desired set list value

Tags: windows, list, batch-file, cmd, modbus

the code below is for printing a command line based on the 2 sets

```
@echo off

rem Define lists of register addresses and values to write
set MY_REG_ADDRESSES=3 22 28 29 31 32 21 51 94 97 104 105 77
set MY_REG_VALUES=4 12000 450 40 100 40 1440 100 450 10000 0 0 1000

rem Write values to Modbus registers using the lists
set i=0
for %%a in (%MY_REG_ADDRESSES%) do (
    set /a i=i+1
    echo modpoll -r %%a -t 4 -4 1  COM3 !MY_REG_VALUES:~%i%,1!
)
```

I would expect the code to output lines that look like:

```
modpoll -r 3 -t 4 -4 1  COM3 4
```

but rather I am getting:

```
modpoll -r 3 -t 4 -4 1  COM3 !MY_REG_VALUES:~0,1!
```

I have tried using list[i] also but that returned nothing??

Comment: To begin with, where have you enabled delayed expansion?

Comment: if include that it works but then won't iterate i in the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you're trying to do!

*It may not be the most efficient way to do it, but as long as your lists aren't super long, it should work perfectly well for you.*

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem Define lists of register addresses and values to write
Set "MY_REG_ADDRESSES=3 22 28 29 31 32 21 51 94 97 104 105 77"
Set "MY_REG_VALUES=4 12000 450 40 100 40 1440 100 450 10000 0 0 1000"

Rem Write values to Modbus registers using the lists
Set "Acount=0"
For %%G In (%MY_REG_ADDRESSES%) Do (
    Set /A Acount += 1, Vcount=0
    For %%H In (%MY_REG_VALUES%) Do (
        Set /A Vcount += 1
        If !Acount! Equ !Vcount! Echo modpoll -r %%G -t 4 -4 1  COM3 %%H
    )
)

Pause
```

Obviously the last line is optional, *(I just included it so you could see the results, if you double-clicked the script)*.